# Risk of malware when uploading/downloading user files

Tags: security, amazon-s3, malware

I'm building a social app, where users can choose what profile-picture they wish to display to others. I've currently implemented it as the following:

1. User sends the profile-picture file to my server
2. My server validates that the file size is not too large
3. My server uploads the file to a AWS S3 bucket, with a UUID prefix
4. The S3 bucket allows anyone in the world to download specific files, but not perform write/list operations
5. I store the profile-picture URL in my database, and send the link to other users as appropriate
6. The client for other users, upon encountering the profile-picture URL, will download the file and display it to the user

I'm now wondering if it's possible for a malicious user to upload a malware-file as his profile-picture, and take advantage of the fact that this malware will be stored in my S3 bucket, and downloaded onto many other users' phones.

How much of a concern is the above? Is there anything simple I can do to prevent such concerns? If not, what is the recommended way to store/distribute user-uploaded profile-pictures to others?

Edit: My server is in Java. Any Java specific library/tool advice will be appreciated as well

Comment: It's certainly possible to upload malware as an image. Other than validating the MIME of a file (I'm unsure if AWS can do this), there's not much you can do to prevent malicious image uploads. Having said that, malicious images are very rare -- almost to the extent of not needing to worry about them. Depending on what server-side languages you are using, you **can** verify that an image is actually an 'image', though in most situations just limiting the file extensions to images will suffice.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your programming environment but there are libraries available to make an educated guess at the file type.  Assuming that you're limiting to just a few legitimate file types you could use these libraries to double validate.  For example, in Java [here is a decent article](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/02/determining-file-types-in-java.html) on utilizing both built-in and 3rd party libraries.  It's not 100% but, for example, you won't except a `.exe` file.

Comment: You need to be processing images, anyway, to strip them of EXIF metadata that might give away the user's location (GPS coordinates) to anyone downloading the images.  If the file is not a valid image, you can detect it during that process.  If it's a profile picture, you will probably want to normalize it to the correct aspect ratio, too, and potentially do other modifications.